# Possible to extend by continuity a function not defined in a hyperplane of its domain?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, metric-spaces

My main question is if it's possible to extend by continuity a function not defined in a hyperplane of its domain?

For example, let $f:\mathbb{R}^2\setminus L\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, where $L$ is a line. All the points of $L$ belong to the closure of the domain, but the domain of the function is an open set. Is this function capable of being extended to the whole space $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: Let's assume also that $f$ is uniformly continuous.

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in general as already the function $z=\frac{1}{x}$ illustrates.  However if one assumes the function to have the stronger property of *uniform* continuity then indeed it can be extended across the hyperplane in a continuous fashion.

Comment: Mikhail, thanks for your answer. What theorem could I use?

Comment: I am not sure if there is an official theorem that you could use here but at any rate given a point $p$ in the hyperplane try to show that, given a sequence of points converging to $p$, the values of the function also converge, under the hypothesis of uniform continuity.

Comment: You may be interested in the fact that in the hyperreal framework, the solution is particularly elegant and transparent.  Here what you do is to choose an infinitely close point $x$ to $p$.  First you show that $f(x)$ is finite so that the standard part is well-defined; then you define $f(p)$ to be the standard part of $f(x)$. For additional details see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_continuity#Non-standard_analysis

Comment: It seems a bit too complex for me...  I was hopping for an 'official' theorem.

Comment: +1, but I'll wait to see if other answers show up. ;)

Comment: One relevant fact is that if $f$ is uniformly continuous on an open interval $(a,b)$ then $f$ extends by continuity to the boundary points.